# Push metadata in array wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**Applying meta keys in search result**

Since I need to take on a different approach to get my data in javascript from wordpress, I am trying to apply (as follow up on my post earlier today (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873986/javascript-for-each-custom-post-type-wordpress)) metadata to my query so it will spit out the right information. This is practically harder than I thought, cause I preferly want it in one query. I been googling now for quite a while, cause I had hoped I wasn't the only one with this problem. I cant seem to find a relevant answer to my problem

**Case**

Since I was being pointed to the fact javascript and php dont play nice, I was beginning to explore a different way. It requires me to get the results on forehand before I push this into javascript via a `json_encode`. So far this is running fine, except for one tiny thing. When asking in WP_query I cant get any meta data, which is the part I really need, since that contain map information for my google maps. So is there a way I can query that before I push this through?

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'hotels',
 );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($query->posts);
echo '</pre>'
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var post_info = <?php echo json_encode($query->posts); ?>;
<script>
```

So far I managed to check what is been given, but I sume, I cant get this via wp_query. Is there another way to actually get the data I need? Or is there a way I can push the meta data in the array with each single post, so I can acces it in Javascript?

Comment: This would probably be easier if you wrote the SQL to query the data yourself, so that you can easily JOIN the posts with their meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for get_post_meta() ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

But you will have to call get_post_meta on each post :/

EDIT :

```
<?php 
  foreach($query->posts as $post) {
    $post->meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thats the thing, I am trying to get this meta data before it runs through to the javascript, because I cannot call this function when I am in the javascript itself. Else it would be a piece of cake. My loop for the map information is being set by the array i put in `post_info`. Because JS doesnt allow me to make a call to get_post_meta, i have to do this on forhand and push into the array. I just dont know how. Else I have to write a custom query

Comment: I edited my answer, does it help ? (there is now a Rest api on wordpress so you actually use js to make call)

Comment: You are awesome. Exactly what I needed.